# Personalize error messages for unique key mySQL

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, forms

I made a formular for a subscription with a name, a phone number and a comment. I put a unique key on the phone in my database to avoid several entries with the same number.
As the message error is incomprehensible

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0600000000' for key 'telephone' in C:\xampp\htdocs\sitesweb\formulaire\inscription.php:28 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\sitesweb\formulaire\inscription.php(28): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sitesweb\formulaire\inscription.php on line 28
```

I decided to personalized it.
I put a try / catch.
The try / catch works almost perfectly

i coded it like that

```
try{
here my sql request ...
}
 catch( PDOException $e ) {
    error_log($e -> getMessage());
    if($e->getCode()==23000){
            echo '<span class="titre_form">The phone number is already exist.</span>';
    }else{
        echo '<span class="titre_form">Thanks this person is added to the database</span>';      
    }
}
```

The script work good (a phone number existing is not added a second time and a phone not existing is added so it is ok).

My problem is the first message of my `if` condition (when a phone already exist) is well displayed, but the message of the `else` "Thanks this person is added to the database" is not displayed (I have only my background).

Is it normal ? Or did I make an error in my code ?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is there even an exception thrown when nothing is going wrong? Also, please do not use irrelevant tags - the given problem is not related to HTML, CSS, or forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not going on the `else` statement since exception are supposed to be "error" but it actually manage to write it on database ...

do something like this

```
$exist  = "no";

try{
here my sql request ...
}
 catch( PDOException $e ) {
    error_log($e -> getMessage());
    if($e->getCode()==23000){
            echo '<span class="titre_form">The phone number is already exist.</span>';
            $exist  = "yes";
    }
}

if ($exist == "no") {
        echo '<span class="titre_form">Thanks this person is added to the database</span>';      
    }
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot, it works perfecty !!!! Many thanks

Comment: That's good to hear that it actually solve your concern if you have more question feel to post another one there are more proficient people that can help also if i manage to solve your question on this post you can mark my answer as solution by clicking the check button beside it ...